# Layover in Seattle on a B1/B2, then drive to US on same week

Tags: visas, transit, b1-b2-visas, tourist-visas

My family and I planned to long drive to Vegas from Canada so I obtained a B1/B2 visa. Im a canadian permanent resident but is currently in the Philippines studying college. My fam also has their visas and have been on a trip to vegas from canada last summer for 3 weeks.

The plan is Ill fly to Canada then long drive from there to the US. (My family loves driving haha). The problem is the cheapest flight I could book passes through Seattle before Canada. Would it be weird if I pass through US for my 9hour layover then fly to Canada then from there drive and stay in the US for 3 weeks which is our original vacation plan? After three weeks Ill be coming back to Canada then taking my return flight which passes through Seattle again.

So here is an illustration:
MNL-NRT-SEA-CA (flight to canada)

CA-Vegas-CA (drive and vacation to vegas)

CA-SEA-NRT-MNL (flight back home)

Thanks for your help everyone Im scared of getting denied entry even if I have a visa and my intentions are clean

Comment: I dont know how long the drive is but we plan to stay in Vegas for 3 weeks staying with my dad's brother. :-)

Comment: Do you have a single or multiple entry B1/B2 visa? Your plan requires entering the US three separate times.

Comment: @Zach I have a 10 year multiple entry B1/B2 visa. :-)

Answer (score 2):

There's no problem with this itinerary on multiple entry B1/B2 visas. Such visas are also good for transit, in addition to business and tourism.

The only situation in which you might have a problem is if you *fly* into the US and then *drive* into Canada. But this doesn't seem to be anywhere on your itinerary. (In this case you should inform the immigration officer when you arrive on your flight, so that you can get an old-school paper I-94W form to turn in when you drive to Canada, as departures from the US by land are not otherwise tracked.)

Most likely what will happen with your specific itinerary is that you will get a stamp admitting you to the US for six months on your initial entry, and then for your next two entries, you'll re-enter under *automatic revalidation*, a slightly expedited process which lets you come back in under the time remaining on your previous six month admission stamp.

Comment: thank you so much that puts my mind to ease! I basically just chose to transit through seattle because it's one of the cheapest that do not pass through China (been there a lot and wanted something different) and I figured I'd see seattle along the way in that 9 hours.